# PlayerPrefs not saving high score.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an endless game where the score increases based off of Time.fixedDeltaTime. I'm trying to store a high score in player preferences if it is higher than the earned score but it doesn't seem to be sticking. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm storing scores in a PlayerPrefs using the HUDScript and presenting score and high score in game over scene using the GameOverScript.

```
        using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HUDScript : MonoBehaviour {

    float playerScore = 0;
    public Text scoreText;

    float highScore;
    public Text highScoreText;

    void Start () {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore", 0);
    }


    void Update () {
        playerScore += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round((playerScore * 100)).ToString();
        if (playerScore > highScore) {
            highScore = playerScore;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Highscore", Mathf.Round (highScore * 100));
            PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        }

    }

    public void IncreaseScore(int amount){
        playerScore += amount;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Score", Mathf.Round((playerScore * 100)));
    }
}

    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameOverScript : MonoBehaviour {

    HUDScript hud;
    float score = 0;
    float highScore;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Score");
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString ();
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore");
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore.ToString ();
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }
```

}

Comment: just an advice, the saving code in `HUDScript.Update` should be removed.  And when will HUDScript become disable?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it because the GameOver highscore is the previous game's highscore and not the most recent? I would like to help but your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry my ask was not completely clear. My exact problem is the high score stored in PlayerPrefs does not stick when the game is restarted. I'm trying to show a locally persistent high score. Right now if you restart the game, the score and high score are identical every play through.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by moving the high score checking logic to the GameOver script. I'm new to  Unity and C# so this wasn't obvious to me until after my third cup of coffee. Thanks and sorry for the ambiguity.

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HUDScript : MonoBehaviour {

    float playerScore = 0;
    public Text scoreText;


    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
        playerScore += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round((playerScore * 100)).ToString();

    }


    public void IncreaseScore(int amount){
        playerScore += amount;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Score", Mathf.Round((playerScore * 100)));

    }

}

    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameOverScript : MonoBehaviour {

    HUDScript hud;
    float score = 0;
    float highScore;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Score");
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("HighScore", 0);

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString ();
        if (score > highScore) {
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + score.ToString ();
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", score);
        } else {
            highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore.ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but it's kind of weird that you are multiplying your high score by 100 when saving the value, but not when loading it. This might be causing errors, something like this:

```
Current high score: 0
Game 1: Load current high score: 0. Final player score: 5. Save current high score: 500.
Current high score: 500
Game 2: Load current high score: 500. Final player score: 7. 7 < 500. No high score saved.
```

Perhaps you shouldn't do the Mathf.Round(playerScore * 100) thing when saving?

Answer (score -1):

It is inefficient and may error-prone (like in your case) to continuously save score in update (it is not make sense too). I recommend you to store score (based on your condition_ as user finish the game.

And please also make ***playerScore*** , ***highScore*** variable public so that you can watch and confirm is value for testing purpose.